# Array Index Out of Bounds Project Euler Problem 17

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm currently stuck on problem 17 in Project Euler. a little background: My program works fine for numbers 1- 120. once I get past 120, its not using the modulo operator in the way I've intended. I'm trying to fix it, but for previous iterations of this problem, the division and remainder functions are working correctly, so I'm trying to figure out what's changed that's causing an error on the conditional (I >= 120 && I < 1000)(Ps, don't care about optimizing, I'm a programming student and just working on creating and getting comfortable with arrays). thanks!

I've tried using my division and remainder operators at different times, such as s+= ones[division(I)]  on the (I >= 120 && I < 1000) conditional and haven't fixed the error.

```
public class LetterCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        String[] ones = {"","one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten","eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", ""};
        String[] tens = {"", "","twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", ""};
        String[] hundreds = {"","onehundred", "twohundred", "threehundred", "fourhundred", "fivehundred", "sixhunded", "sevenhundred", "eighthundred", "ninehundred"};
        String[] thousand = {"", "onethousand"};
         String s  = new String();
         for(i = 0; i <= 126; i++) {
             if(i <= 20) {
                 s+= ones[i];
             }
             if(i == 20) {
                 //performs i / 10
                 s+= tens[division(i)];
             }
             if(i > 20 && i < 100) {
                 //performs i / 10 & i % 10
                 s+= tens[division(i)];
                 s+= ones[remainder(i)];
             } if (i == 100) {
                 //performs i / 100
                 s+= hundreds[division(i)];
             } if (i > 100 && i < 120) {
                 //performs i / 10, i % 10, and i / 100
                 s+= hundreds[division(i)];
                 s+= tens[division(i)];
                 s+= ones[remainder(i)];

             } if (i >= 120 && i < 1000) {
                 //performs i / 100, i / 10, and i % 10
                s+= hundreds[division(i)];
                s+= tens[division(i)];
                s+= ones[remainder(i)];


             } if (i == 1000) {
                 s+= thousand[division(i)];
             }
         }
         System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static int remainder(int i) {
        if (i >= 100 && i <= 1000) {
            return i % 100;
        } else if(i > 10 && i < 100) {
            return i % 10;
        }
        return i;
    }
    public static int division(int i) {
        if (i == 1000) {
        return i / 1000;
        } 
        if (i >= 100 && i <= 1000) {
            return i / 100;
        } if (i < 100)  {
            return i / 10;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: How do you get the tens digit from `120`?

Comment: You can use a string and call `Integer.parseInt(String.charAt(String.length()-2)+"");`

Answer (score 2):

Your `ones` array **length = 21**
So the last element you can access it will be `ones[20]`
But in your function `remainder(int i)`, you can return values up to **99**
Because your method contains this line `return i % 100;`
So when you will use `ones[remainder(i)];`
You will face `Array Index Out of Bounds` normally **if the returned reminder value > 20**